Different results in HIVE and LLAP query when filtering by date
I have an strange error. My query return different values if using HIVE or using LLAP. I identified that is due to a filter in a timestamp field.
This query returns the correct number of values when using LLAP:
select * from mytable where dt_ref="2023-12-31"

but it just returns an small subset of the expected values when using hive.
if I change the query to use the to_date method, it returns all the expected values:
select * from mytable where to_date(dt_ref)="2023-12-31"

It looks like a bug, but I can't update the HIVE engine by now. Any idea how to prevent this different behavior?

Maybe some of the dates are timestamps?

@foglerit the column type is timestamp.

exactly, what do you expect the result of dt_ref="2023-12-31" to be if the column has timestamps instead of dates?

What I really expect is the same answer from Hive and LLAP :-) My user expects it to match the date part, at least if the time part is all zeros. @foglerit
